# How to make a component appear after the page has loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Newsletter component that I want to show when the page has loaded as a popup. Right now it get's displayed after a click on a button, how can I do that? I know there is react-popup but I don't want to do it that way, here is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './newsletter.css';

class Newsletter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      modalOpened: false
    };

    this.modalToggle = this.modalToggle.bind(this);
  }

  modalToggle() {
    this.setState({ modalOpened: !this.state.modalOpened });
  }

  render() {
    const coverClass = this.state.modalOpened ? 'modal-cover modal-cover-active' : 'modal-cover';
    const containerClass = this.state.modalOpened ? 'modal-container modal-container-active' : 'modal-container';

    return (
      <div>
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.modalToggle}>
          Sign up for our Newsletter!
        </button>

        <div className={containerClass}>
          <div className="modal-header" />
          <h1> Want more offers? Sign Up! </h1>
          <div className="modal-body">
            <form action="#" className="form">
              <input type="email" className="input" />
              <input className="newsletter-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-footer" />
        </div>

        <div className={coverClass} onClick={this.modalToggle} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Newsletter;
```

I tried putting it in a ComponentWillMount cycle but it did not work, how can I do that?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the modal to show directly when the component is created, you can default `modalOpened` to `true` instead of `false` in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    modalOpened: true
  };

  this.modalToggle = this.modalToggle.bind(this);
}
```

If you want to show the modal after a certain amount of time, you could use a `setTimeout` that uses `setState` after a certain amount of time has elapsed.

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => this.setState({ modalOpened: true }), 3000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking about doing it with a timeout, for example load the modal after a minute or so, I tried modalOpened: setTimeout(false, 3000) but it didn't work how should it be done?